# python selenium break off when access all 'a' tags

Tags: python, selenium

I can access all 'a' tags using Python+selenium in "https://www.zillow.com/homes/recently_sold/Culver-City-CA/house,condo,apartment_duplex,townhouse_type/51617_rid/12m_days/globalrelevanceex_sort/34.044908,-118.348417,33.961088,-118.468924_rect/12_zm/",which means all 'house detail' hyperlinks.But it breaks off when I get into every page to crawl information,that's what troubles me.I want the code can crawl all information in 26 pages successfully.Thank you!

```
# coding : utf-8

from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

def crawlHouseDetailForInvoke():
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("collapsible-header").click()# price/tax history
        time.sleep(5)
    table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id = "wrapper"]//div[@id = "detail-container-column"]//section[3]/div[@id = "tax-price-history"]/div[@id = "hdp-price-history"]/div/table')
    print(table.text)
except Exception:
    print("读取数据失败！")

def crawlRegion(url):
    driver.get(url)
    page_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id = "search-pagination-wrapper"]/ol/li/a')
    print("站内页面数为：%d" % len(page_links))
    house_link_parent = driver.find_element_by_id('list-results')
    house_links = house_link_parent.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id = "search-results"]/ul/li/article/div/a')
    print("每页的房源信息数：%d" % len(house_links))
    times = 0
    for j in range(len(house_links)):
        times = times + 1
        if(times%9 == 0):
            print("元素重加载完成...")
            house_link_parent = driver.find_element_by_id('list-results')
            house_links = house_link_parent.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id = "search-results"]/ul/li/article/div/a')
        print("序号：%d" % j)
        print("链接：%s" % house_links[j].get_attribute("href"))
        house_links[j].click()
    time.sleep(8)
    crawlHouseDetailForInvoke()
    driver.back()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    regionUrl = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/recently_sold/Culver-City-CA/house,condo,apartment_duplex,townhouse_type/51617_rid/12m_days/globalrelevanceex_sort/34.05529,-118.33211,33.956531,-118.485919_rect/12_zm/"
    print("crawler is started...")

    crawlRegion(regionUrl)

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: This is not a question. It's a debugging request on a code base that has nothing minimal about it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer！So it's there a resolution？Or how should I modify my code to resolve it？

Comment: As it stands, your question is going to get closed down  pretty soon  because it is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: Oh,sorry.Thanks again.I cant clearly understand your first answer,so I ask again.Do you mean that my intention is not polite for zillow site,and I'm prevent by the site manager?

Comment: No. I am implying that your question is not likely to get the answer you are looking for on Stack Overflow because it does not follow site rules.

Comment: OK,I see.Thank you.